# How to fix “sub process usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code 1″ Error in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

When i tried `sudo apt upgrade`
it says:

```
Setting up nvidia-dkms-390 (390.132-0ubuntu0.19.10.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
Removing old nvidia-390.132 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 390.132
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new nvidia-390.132 DKMS files...
Building for 5.5.0-16.2-liquorix-amd64
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.5.0-16.2-liquorix-amd64
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.5.0-16.2-liquorix-amd64 is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.5.0-16.2-liquorix-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/390.132/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-390 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-390 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit sta
tus 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-390:
 nvidia-driver-390 depends on nvidia-dkms-390 (= 390.132-0ubuntu0.19.10.1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-390 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-390 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previ
ous failure.
            Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.133ubuntu10) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.5.0-16.2-liquorix-amd64
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3.fw for module r8169
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-390
 nvidia-driver-390
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can u help me, I tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, `sudo apt-get install -f` but it doesn't worked for me! PLS HELP! I can,t finish my work cause of this!

Answer (score 1):

The NVidia drivers need to be patched for kernel 5.5 (and then for 5.6, too). It seems that, unfortunately, Ubuntu doesn't have a patched version yet, however, Debian does. [Here](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/nvidia-legacy-390xx-kernel-dkms), in revision -3, they patched for 5.5 and in -4 for 5.6. I would just download the *nvidia-...-dkms* package for your architecture from there and install it with `dpkg`. There's nothing in the package that shouldn't work with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running a version of Ubuntu, you could try running the Software Updater utility and check the  'Additional Drivers' tab to see if the Nvidia driver can be removed/reinstalled/upgraded from there.

Answer (score 0):

I've previously have applied of the solutions for black screen upon the load and that was causing the issue after recent software updates. I removed dis_ucode_ldr and nouveau.modeset=0 from the setting below in /etc/default/grub and it worked:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="dis_ucode_ldr quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"